# Get Values in Iframe based UI Dialog from parent form having Master Page in ASP.NET using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a Master Page based User entry form in asp.net. When user Clicks on a button it opens Jquery ui dialog popup in iframe . I have to access the values of text boxes of the parent entry form and pre-fill those in the popup.

**Button Click on Entry form**

```
 $(function () {
 $("input[id$='btnTccDetails']").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                var horizontalPadding = 30;
                var verticalPadding = 30;
                $('<iframe id="externalSite" class="externalSite" src="' + 'tccDetails.aspx?action=ADD' + '" />').dialog({
                    title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'TCC Details',
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 1200,
                    height: 600,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    autoResize: true,
                    overlay: {
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        background: "black"
                    },
                    open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); }
                }).width(1200 - horizontalPadding).height(600 - verticalPadding);

            }); 


        });   //end of function()
```

// Popup   Javascript

I was able to use the regular javascript .
var tag = window.parent.document.forms[0].ctl00_MainContentHolder_txtTag.value;

I need to do this in Jquery. I have tried this

```
   var tag = window.parent.jQuery('#txtTag').val();
```

This does not work.

I have tried searching all the related post on here without much luck.

**Solution:

```
var tag = $("input[id$='txtTag']", window.parent.document).val();**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will need to specify the context of the selector like so:

```
$('#txtTag', window.parent.document).val();
```

(From the [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) documentation)

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

Using this second parameter you can pass in the parent document in which JQuery will search for the input element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution jdavies. I have to modify your approach, Following is the solution  $("input[id$='txtTag']", window.parent.document).val();